# Why won't both of these seemingly same implementations cause an overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So as expected, the following jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function animate1(){

    var div = $("#circle"); 
    var xcor,ycor;
    xcor = Math.random()*100; ycor=Math.random()*100;

    div.animate({left: xcor, top:ycor}, "slow", animate1());
});
```

would cause a stack overflow
but how come 
the following function wouldn't?

```
$(document).ready(function animate1(){

    var div = $("#circle"); 
    var xcor,ycor;
    xcor = Math.random()*100; ycor=Math.random()*100;

    div.animate({left: xcor, top:ycor}, "slow", function () {animate1();});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are executing `animate1()` in the process of calling `div.animate`. That's what causes the overflow. In the second case, you are not; the completion function calls `animate1()` only after the animation completes. In the first case, you could try using `animate1` instead of `animate1()` as the completion argument.

```
div.animate({left: xcor, top:ycor}, "slow", animate1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.animate({left: xcor, top:ycor}, "slow", animate1());
```

You are immediately calling animate1 there instead of giving animate a function reference.  This means the logic is going to start a very fast endless recursion loop without releasing previously gotten resources.

```
div.animate({left: xcor, top:ycor}, "slow", function () {animate1();});
```

This one gives a proper callback which will not cause the immediate invocation and will allow resources to be released.